# iPhone: Possible to turn on/off Location Services in app?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, currentlocation

Does anyone know if it's possible to turn location services on and off from within an app? Say I have an app, I select OK when asked if I want the app to use my current location, but later I decide that I want to disallow the app to use my location. I know there's a toggle in Settings that will turn the feature on and off per app, but I'm wondering if I can provide a means within my app for the user to manage that selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the settings from the app, but certainly you can make a switch that stops monitoring for location changes.